# Insert row of table into textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, textbox

I have `DataGrid` and below it some textboxes in my WPF project. I decide to clean the `DataGrid` but still remain for textboxes "like" below:

[image: Screenshot]

I use this code when I had `DataGrid`:

```
     var query = (from d1 in database.vw_Employee
                               select new
                               {
                                   d1.EmpID,
                                   d1.EmpFName,
                                   d1.EmpLName,
                                   d1.EmpTitle,
                               }).ToList().First();
    
                
                    txt_IdEmp.Text = query.EmpID.ToString();
                    txt_FNameEmp.Text = query.EmpFName;
                    txt_LNameEmp.Text = query.EmpLName;
                    txt_TitleEmp.Text = query.EmpTitle;
```

So I want it works without `DataGrid` and insert the first row of the table into textboxes. Any help?

Comment: "What's wrong?" Probably your shift-key, I couldn't see a single uppercase letter in the whole question... Please read [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What's wrong with the above code?

Comment: @farzadini, I edited your question in order to have more correctness about grammar, syntax, code formatting, and the general presentation (like embedding the image inside the question instead of leaving it as an external link). If you reject my edit and prefer to have a question written in a bad English and with bad formatting, you are free to do so, but don't expect the appreciation of the other SO users. Goodbye.

Comment: after i click it shows this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandCompilationException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Comment: Did it ever work?

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus . tnx for your correctness. i mistakenly reject your work.

Comment: @mm8 it works as i had datagridview beside these textboxes

Answer (score 1):

This should work provided that there is at least one `Employee` enity present in `vw_Employee`:

```
var employees = (from d1 in database.vw_Employee
                select d1).ToList();

if(employees != null && employees.Count > 0)
{
    txt_IdEmp.Text = employees[0].EmpID.ToString();
    txt_FNameEmp.Text = employees[0].EmpFName;
    txt_LNameEmp.Text = employees[0].EmpLName;
    txt_TitleEmp.Text = employees[0].EmpTitle;
}
```

Comment: no it makes the same error try First(), Last(), FirstOrDefault(); no diffrences

Comment: employees has no .Count . it's got only feild of my table(vw_Employee)

Comment: i check with other table . also has no Count. Sorry :(

Comment: Then there are no items in vw_Employee.

Comment: is there any simillar question . i could have a look on that?

Comment: No one but you can be supposed to know what data that your view or table contains...